# Understanding Lemma 4.14 on real analysis by Folland

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> 4.14: Given a Normal Topological Space $X$ and any disjoint closed sets $A,B$ there exists a set $\Delta=\{k2^{-n}:n\geq 1, 0<k<2^n\}$ such that $A\subset U_r \subset B^c$ for all $r\in \Delta$ and $\overline{U_r}\subset U_s$ for all $s>r$ in $\Delta$.

> Proof: By normality there exists $V,W$ disjoint opens sets that contains $A,B$ respectively, then since $\overline{V},W^c$ are closed sets, and $A\subset W^c$ we must have $\overline{V}\subset W^c$. Set $U_{\frac{1}{2}}=V$ we have $$A\subset U_{\frac{1}{2}}\subset \overline{U_{\frac{1}{2}}}\subset W^c\subset B^c$$
> Then select $U_r, r=k2^{-n}$ by induction on $n$. Suppose we have chosen $U_r$ for $r=k2^{-n}$, when $0<k<2^{n}$ and $n<N-1$. To find $U_r$ for $r=(2j+1)2^{-N}(0 \leq j <2^{N-1})$ Observe that $U_{j2^{1-N}}$ and $\overline{U_{(j+1)2^{1-N}}}^c$ are disjoint closed sets (where $\overline{U}_0=A$ and $U_1^c=B$), So as above we can choose $U_r$ with $$A\subset U_{j2^{1-N}} \subset U_r\subset \overline{U}_r \subset U_{(j+1)2^{1-N}}\subset B^c  $$ , Completing the proof.

My confusion lies after the first nested sets, where it says "Then select $U_r$..." anything after that doesn't make much sense to me can anyone help me understand it? Thanks!

Comment: It is just a sequence of applications of the Uryshohn's lemma and a clever ordering of dyadic numbers starting with $D_0=\{0,1\}$, $D_1=\{1/2\}$, $D_2=\{\frac1/4,3/4\}$,\ldots $D_n=\{k2^{n-1}: k\equiv1\mod 2, 1\leq k\leq 2^n-1\}$.